# FTP reports 644 on file but is_writable(file) returns false

Tags: php, permissions

FTP reports 644 on file but is_writable(file) returns false

What am I missing?

Comment: First of all, stuff like which FTP Server you are using, what configuration and what users would be good. Second, this is more a topic for ServerFault than StackOverflow.

Comment: @Boo: No, it's relevant to PHP, so it can belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File might be writable to ftp user, but not for the user that runs php code (eg. www-data or apache).

Comment: +1 Thanks. so I should ask the webserver host to make the change or can I do it via FTP?

Comment: If possible, running php with user rights is the best option, but not available on many hosts, so you can either change all files and folders to 777 (not recommended) or use ftp_* functions in php, connect to localhost and overwrite the file you wish to change.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the owner / group of the file in question as well as the account you are connecting with. Keep in mind that 644 is user(rw) group(r) world(r), so if the file is not owned by whatever account is connecting via FTP, you will only have read access... and is_writable(file) will correctly return false.